# Erlang exmpp get body from Packet

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I need to get *body* attribute from input xmpp Packet with Erlang/xmpp.

I receive packet:

```
 Record = #received_packet{packet_type=message,
                  raw_packet=Packet,
                  from=From,
                  type_attr=Type} when Type =/= "error
```

How can i extract body message from `Packet`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using exmpp you can use module exmpp_message:get_body/1

http://www.process-one.net/docs/exmpp/devdoc/trunk/exmpp_message.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already went through exmpp examples. Here is a snippet from echo_client.erl example:

```
%% Send the same packet back for each message received
echo_packet(MySession, Packet) ->
    From = exmpp_xml:get_attribute(Packet, <<"from">>, <<"unknown">>),
    To = exmpp_xml:get_attribute(Packet, <<"to">>, <<"unknown">>),
    TmpPacket = exmpp_xml:set_attribute(Packet, <<"from">>, To),
    TmpPacket2 = exmpp_xml:set_attribute(TmpPacket, <<"to">>, From),
    NewPacket = exmpp_xml:remove_attribute(TmpPacket2, <<"id">>),
    exmpp_session:send_packet(MySession, NewPacket).
```